# Make says "missing separator" for source .c file from CuTest

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to get started with CuTest to do unit testing in C.

When make-ing, I get the following error:

```
dev:~/bistro# make
cutest/CuTest.c:10: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

---

The file `cutest/CuTest.c` comes directly from the library. I have done no mods to it. Here are the concerned lines:

```
08 - #include "CuTest.h"
09 - 
10 - /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
11 -  * CuStr
12 -  *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
13 - 
14 - char* CuStrAlloc(int size)
```

---

Here's the Makefile I'm using, for complete reference:

```
NAME = bistro

SOURCES_DIR = src
OBJECTS_DIR = obj
SOURCES = $(shell find $(SOURCES_DIR) -type f -name *.c) cutest/CuTest.c
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCES_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPS    = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra
COMPILER = gcc -I cutest -I $(SOURCES_DIR) $(CFLAGS)

BISTRO_MAIN = $(OBJECTS_DIR)/bistro/bistro_main.o

.PHONY: test all clean fclean re
all: $(NAME)

# header dependencies
-include $(DEPS)

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILER) -o $(NAME) $(OBJECTS)
test: $(filter-out $(BISTRO_MAIN), $(OBJECTS))
    $(COMPILER) -c all_tests.c -o all_tests.o
    $(COMPILER) -o test $(filter-out $(BISTRO_MAIN), $(OBJECTS)) all_tests.o
    rm -f all_tests.o
$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%.c
    @if [ ! -d "$(@D)" ]; then mkdir -p $(@D); fi
    $(COMPILER) -MMD -c $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -Rf $(OBJECTS_DIR)/*
fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)
re: fclean all
```

---

**What could be the cause of this error message?**

*EDIT 1:* The makefile is indented with 4-space tabs only. Could the call to the "find" command be the cause of that? Also, how come the error says the missing separator is in the .c file?

*EDIT 2:* The accepted answer shows the error. In addition, the call did not work because it was searching for `*.c`, which should be `"*.c"`.

Comment: A possible cause for this error message can be, that the makefile contains spaces for indentation, not tabs.

Comment: The makefile is indented with 4-space tabs only. Could the call to the "find" command be the cause of that? Also, how come the error says the missing separator is in the .c file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you are using (four) spaces instead of `tab` symbol.

Make target's command must be indented with a `tab`.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction:

> Please note: you need to put a tab character at the beginning of every recipe line! This is an obscurity that catches the unwary. If you prefer to prefix your recipes with a character other than tab, you can set the .RECIPEPREFIX variable to an alternate character

---

Your error comes because you include a C source file into Makefile.

```
SOURCES = $(shell find $(SOURCES_DIR) -type f -name *.c) cutest/CuTest.c
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCES_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES)) # cutest/CuTest.c stays cutest/CuTest.c
DEPS    = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
-include $(DEPS) # oops, includes cutest/CuTest.c
```

Comment: The Makefile is indented with 4-space tabs only. I've added this to the question as well so new readers can see it right away. Thanks for your help :-)